# Can I use Stack Overflow usernames in an academic paper?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users, display-names

I am writing a paper about Stack Overflow users, and I would like to mention some interesting findings about some users of the SO community. Is it OK to do so? Do I have to ask them personally or should I use an alias or their userID?

Comment: Ask them directly ?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279407/is-there-a-proper-way-to-ask-for-a-users-real-name (also asking about crediting users)

Comment: The problem with asking all the users I need is that they are too many. If I use their usernames, am I breaking any Stack Exchange rules?

Comment: I personally would have a problem with something like this